# Getting data from gridview to textbox in asp.net c# using link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

Here is my aspx.cs page code. Every time when I run the code the only answer I get is: Column name doesn't exist.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
  CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
  <Columns>

   <asp:BoundField DataField="TutorialId"  HeaderText="Tutorial Id"/>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="TutorialTitle" HeaderText="TutorialTitle"/>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="CatId" HeaderText="Category Id" />

   <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkview" runat="server" OnClick="lnk_OnClick"
             CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TutorialId") %>'>View</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my aspx code. Here I have used click event on the link 
button which is getting the ID number:

```
protected void lnk_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int TutorialId = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    GetTutorialById();
}

private void GetTutorialById()
{
    OnlineSubjects onlinesubject = new OnlineSubjects();
    DataTable dTable = onlinesubject.GetTutorialById();

    txtTutId.Text = dTable.Rows[0]["TutorialId"].ToString();
    txtTitle.Text = dTable.Rows[0]["TutorialTitle"].ToString();
    txtAddTutorial.Text = dTable.Rows[0]["TutorialDesc"].ToString();
}

public DataTable GetTutorialById()
{
    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
    parameters[0] = DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter(
        "@TutorialId", TutorialId, System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 100);

    DataTable dTable = DataLayer.DataAccess.ExecuteDTByProcedure(
        "spTutorialViewById", parameters);

    return dTable;
}
```

Comment: `private void GetTutorialById(int TutorialId)` perhaps a parameter?

Comment: Does this even compile? I mean `TutorialId` does not exist in the context of `GetTutorialById`. As it's declare in an other function and it's not global or anything.

Comment: Yes it get Compiled but the moment i click on the view button it show that column name does not exxist

Comment: I am at begineer level...so if there is any error the plz check it